# My page does not display when adding a javascript tag in the head - jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

Without adding the [javascript file.js] tag into the header of my code, my jquery mobile page shows up. However when i add the tag into the header, my page just displays a blank and does not show any information.

What am i doing wrong?

i've already tried adding the tag before the jquery mobile plugins, after it, etc but it shows the page without the skin of my jquery theme.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/blue.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="images.js"></script>
    <title>House 1</title>
</head>
```

Javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    var imgURL = [];

    imgURL.push('pictures/houses/house1/image1.PNG');
    imgURL.push('pictures/houses/house1/image2.PNG');

    $("#house1").swiperight(function () {
        if (i < (imgURL.length - 1)) {
            i++
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
        var imgStr = "<img src=" + imgURL[i] + " style='width:100%'>";
        $('#popupImg').html(imgStr);
    });
    $("#house1").swipeleft(function () {
        if (i > 0) {
            i--
        } else {
            i = (imgURL.length - 1);
        }
        var imgStr = "<img src=" + imgURL[i] + " style='width:100%'>";
        $('#popupImg').html(imgStr);
    });
});
```

the page should be able to view normally instead of showing a blank page.

Comment: Are you placing the script tag after jQuery.js and the plugins? Order is important. What errors get thrown in browser dev tools console?

Comment: I managed to fix the issue now, for some strange reason it wasn't working for me before but now it shows my page. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Suggest you delete this question then. It is of no future value to anyone

Comment: yes i am trying to delete it but struggling how to

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure to load all libraries and dependencies *before* you include your `<script>` tag for your custom code.  Kindly paste the answer to your issue if already solved?  This greatly helps the community learn.

Comment: im not sure what i did, after posting this question i decided to refresh the page again and the page showed up. i dont know how it worked